# Select and move pdf invoices from one folder to another?

Tags: batch-file

I have a directory with around 82000 `.pdf` files, and need only around 3000 of them.

I am trying to figure out how I can select only the ones that I want, and `move` them to a new directory.

For example, I have:

```
C:\Users\jkelly\Desktop\Clients\TAX\Invoices\INV.655486.pdf
C:\Users\jkelly\Desktop\Clients\TAX\Invoices\INV.655487.pdf
C:\Users\jkelly\Desktop\Clients\TAX\Invoices\INV.655488.pdf
C:\Users\jkelly\Desktop\Clients\TAX\Invoices\INV.655489.pdf
C:\Users\jkelly\Desktop\Clients\TAX\Invoices\INV.655490.pdf
```

All I want to do is be able to `copy` and paste all of the file paths somewhere, and use a command to `move` them to a new directory.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're going through the effort to *copy and paste all of the file paths somewhere*, why can't you just go ahead and copy/paste the files at the same time?

Comment: Which ones are you wishing to select/move, because at present there are a whole host of methods available from a [tag:batch-file].

Comment: I already have the files listed out, so I'm not going through the work of copy and pasting each one. There's about 3,000 that I need to copy and move so I'll look into the batch file link that you sent. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Put the list of file directories in `files.txt` and save this code as a .bat file.

```
@echo off
cls
echo Input destination folder
echo.
set /p fol=Destination:
for /f %%a in (files.txt) do move /-Y %%a %fol%  
exit
```